# Change Odoo Logo in community edition

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I change my company data in odoo community edition but it never reflects eventhough i change in the browser cache. please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axaGz.jpg)

[ODoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axaGz.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You have two option.

1. by UI when you put the mouse over the logo you can clik on update company information.

   [image: click to edit company info]
2. change the logo:
   [image: change logo and save]
3. refresh the page 
   [image]

or you can change it using xml data file:

```xml
    <record id="base.main_partner" model="res.partner">
        <field name="name">Your company name</field>
        <field name="image" type="base64" file="module_name/static/img/logo.png"/>
        <!-- you can edit any field too in the related partner-->
        <field name="street">Street name</field>
        <field name="city">City name</field>
        <field name="zip">16000</field>
        <field name="phone">24 11 11 22</field>
        <field name="email">new@email.com</field>
        <field name="website">www.web-site.com</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: I follow the first process and its still not working, kindly help

Comment: Try to acces with other browser my be it cache,  and you need to change the information of the user company Not other compay

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs due the cache issue (cache re-validation) on odooerp server. As a temporary solution you can try this :

> If you're using Chrome browser then Press F12 key then switch to network  tab and check the Option [Disable Cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL7mC.png) and then refresh your odoo webpage.

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 12 CE when you create a new company it fills the logo field with a value instead of leaving it null (as in the "YourCompany" demo company). You could check this out if the problem persists. The table is res_company, the field logo_web.